# Running GDAL/OGR functions from server on onclick client event

Tags: gis, server-side, gdal, ogr, web-feature-service

This question comes from my poor understanding of how GDAL/OGR is supposed to work server-side, but before trying it I'd like to know if what I want is feasible with this library.

Basically, I am developing a webGIS application where the user should interact with a WFS. I'd like to give the user the possibility to download the data from this WFS as a format that the server does not provide as output so I need to convert it first.

I need the function [ogr2ogr with the WFS](https://www.gdal.org/drv_wfs.html) driver to be able to convert the GML response of the server in (e.g.) Shapefile format.

My very basic question is: how can I call ogr2ogr which is installed on my server when the user click on (e.g.) a "Download" button?

My idea obvioulsy is to tie the onclick event with a JS function that calls ogr2ogr, but here my lack of knowledge in server-side web development does not le me go on.

Am I supposed to prepare a script (like a PHP) that internally calls ogr2ogr, or should I place the GDAL/OGR executables in a cgi-bin folder so that I can point and calling them with the required parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest investigating your server-middleware of choice; there's an excellent chance it supports OGR2OGR already if it's Open Source. The big two:

**GeoServer** has an ogr extension that can do what you want - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/ogr.html

**MapServer** supports OGR too - https://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/output/ogr_output.html

Alternatively, you may want to consider investigating the [WPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Processing_Service) standard - but it's probably overkill if you're just changing formats.

Comment: Well, it's actually QGIS Server, which is quite new and not sure if it supports it. As far as I can see from its GetFeature outputFormat, it only lists GML and GeoJSON. Here is the GetCapabilities link: https://www.wondermap.it/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?&map=/home/ubuntu/qgis/projects/Demo_sci_WMS/demo_sci.qgs&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Comment: @umbe1987 - well, QGISServer will definitely include OGR2OGR inside it, but a quick google doesn't find any obvious way to access it. Try asking on the QGIS user list - https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user - or gis stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will and report what I will discover. Cheers.

Comment: @umbe1987 - True; but I'm already at 5.5k on GIS Stackoverflow so... ;-)

Comment: Just asked on GIS Stackoverflow https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306064/qgis-server-convert-wfs-getfeature-gml-as-shapefile-with-ogr2ogr